# Netbeans: how to create a gradle Java EE project?

Tags: jakarta-ee, gradle, war, packaging, netbeans-8

I'm using Netbeans 8.2. The plugins "Gradle Support" and "Gradle Java EE Support" are both installed and activated. I can create and use simple (non JavaEE) projects in netbeans with Gradle support. This works like a charme :-)

But how can I create a Java EE project with gradle support? If I click "File - New Project... - Gradle" ther are only "Gradle Root Project", "Single Gradle Project" and "Gradle Subprojet". Also in the "Java EE" category I cannot see any new gradle project items...

Anybody knows how can I create a Java EE Project with gradle support in Netbeans?

Comment: Which *kind* of `java-ee` project, and packaged how?

Comment: I have a EAR project with a WAR subproject, a EJB (JAR) project and several other jar's inside. So I have the EAR project, the WAR project and the EJB project which I will integrate into netbeans as gradle projects.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not a complete answer -- because I have the same question!

In an empty directory run `gradle init --type java-library`.  Not sure whether there's a better command more geared towards java-ee.

From Netbeans, create a new project with existing source code.

For the dependencies, that's where it gets a bit hazy.  Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.8' 
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'ear'
}

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart', 'Implementation-Version': '3.4.0'
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.bounceme.doge.json.Main'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'javax.json', name: 'javax.json-api', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.json', version: '1.1'
    provided group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
    providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
}
```

Not that I'm quite sure *how* to import `java-ee` dependencies with gradle, but that should get you started in the right direction.

**Note the `ear` plugin in the first few lines.**  You might want `war` instead.

I'm not too clear on how libs and uber `JAR`'s fit into `EAR` and `WAR` builds with Gradle.

When you get a complete or better answer please post.